# Creating a List from CSV in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot

maybe someone can help.

I want to create a scatter Plot with matlplotlib in python. I have a csv file with x, y values in one row. So it looks like this after importing it in python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvSmi.png)

Now i want to create seperate lists (xdata =[] and ydata = [] for the x values and y values. I wanna work with these lists while creating the scatter plot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZb3Y.png)

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Please don't post images for code.  Answerers don't (and usually won't) re-type your images to answer a question.  Post as text for easy cut and paste.

Comment: alright, will do that in the future.  

Comment: You can edit your current question to remove images and add text.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datapoints.csv', columns = ['x', 'y'])
x = df['x'].tolist()[1:]
y = df['y'].tolist()[1:]
```

Comment: thx, not using pandas makes everything more difficult. ;)